# Direct access to BigTable behind Google Code version control

Tags: version-control, google-code, bigtable

The Mercurial VCS behind Google Code [is backed by BigTable](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/04/mercurial-support-for-project-hosting.html) (I don't know about Subversion).  It can be searched with [Google Codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch) or with [Codesearch Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/codesearch/).  But their feature set is limited, I can't look for the most active projects of the past 100 days, or for files with at least 50 changes.  Is there a way to directly access the BigTable  store and issue such queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, no, there's no lower level access beyond version control and codesearch like what you describe.